# How to wait for a result from a service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 services.  One service (TimeEventService) saves data to a database table.  The other service (ReportingService) is a wrapper for TimeEventService and provides functionality to controllers.

I need the ReportingService to wait for a 'saved' response from the TimeEventService.  What is the best and simplest way to do this please.

TimeEventService code:

```js
angular.module('TimeEventServiceMod', ['ngResource']).
factory('TimeEventService', function(TestTimeEventService,$filter) {

     var timeEventData = {
  savedEvent:null
 };


 timeEventData.newEvent = function(ataskSequenceId,eventNumber){
  var newEvent = new TestTimeEventService();
  newEvent.tasksequenceid = ataskSequenceId;
  newEvent.event = eventNumber;
  newEvent.timeofevent = new Date();

     newEvent.$save(function(){
       timeEventData.newEvent=newEvent;
        console.log('saved  event OK: ' + angular.toJson(timeEventData.newEvent));
        return timeEventData;
     },function (errorResponse) {
         // failure callback
         console.log('error saving Event and new status to  db:' + angular.toJson(errorResponse));
     });
 };
```

ReportingService code:

```js
angular.module('ReportingServiceMod', ['ngResource','TimeEventServiceMod']).
factory('ReportingService', function(TimeEventService) {

    var reportData = {
     lastTimeEventId:-1
 };
 var timeEventData = TimeEventService;

 //the public test events
 reportData.newEvent_testStart = function(ataskSequenceId){newEvent(ataskSequenceId,10)};

 newEvent = function(ataskSequenceId, eventid){
  
  timeEventData = TimeEventService.newEvent(ataskSequenceId,eventid);
  if (timeEventData.savedEvent!=null)
   reportData.lastTimeEventId = timeEventData.savedEvent.id;
  console.log('saved time event id:' + reportData.lastTimeEventId);
 };



     return reportData;
  })
```

Note the line (if (timeEventData.savedEvent!=null)) does not work as the object has not yet been saved.

Comment: When does the `savedEvent` actually get assigned?  I don't see this happening anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
    .run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
    })
    .controller('testController', ['$scope','testFactory1','testFactory2', function($scope, testFactory1, testFactory2){

        testFactory1.firstCall()
         .then(function(reply){
           if(reply){
            testFactory2.secondCall()
             .then(function(reply){
               if(reply){

               }
             },function(err){
               console.log("there was a error", err);
             });
           }
         },function(err){
           console.log("there was a error", err);
         });
    }]).factory('testFactory1',['$http','$q', function($http, $q){
      var ser1 = {
        firstCall : firstCall,
      }
      return ser1;

      function firstCall(){

        var first = $q.defer();
         $http.get(....)
          .then(function(result){
            first.resolve(result.data);
          },function(error){
            first.reject(error.data);
          })
          return first.promise;
      }

    }]).factory('testFactory2',['$http','$q', function(){
      var ser2 = {
        secondCall : secondCall,
      }
      return ser2;

      function secondCall(){

        var second = $q.defer();
         $http.get(....)
          .then(function(result){
            second.resolve(result.data);
          },function(error){
            second.reject(error.data);
          })
          return second.promise;
      }
    }]);
```

Explanation :

```
Why dont you call services from controllers.
here we have two facotries `testFactory1` and `testFactory2` and each have a http call.
So you can call these from controllers one after another.

in 'testController'  you are calling 'firstCall' http function first, and on its sucess we are making 'secondCall',
We can use $q service to wait for secondCall to make till firstCall finishes.
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for your suggestion, but I really want to call the service from my other service. I don't want the controller having to manage how the data needs to be saved in the back-end and I have many many events which need to be dealt with.   Is there a way of using the defer method on a regular function, without any http/resource calls?

Comment: @WaterBoy, you can call a factory function from another factory function

Comment: Hi Again Nikhill, I actually re-worked your example into cascading services and it worked perfectly well!!  Thanks so much for the very clear code.